# Blackmagic Decklink Display Static Images

Tags: c#

I have been asked to implement an application that plays out images to a DeckLink Card.

I have wrote the following code however I find I am getting errors.  Primarily in the Render Image Secton.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<IDeckLink> deckLinks = new List<IDeckLink>();

        IDeckLink dl = null;

        IDeckLinkIterator d = new CDeckLinkIterator();

        while (true)
        {

            d.Next(out dl);

            if (dl == null)
                break;

            deckLinks.Add(dl);


        }


        RenderImage(deckLinks[0]);

    }

    private void RenderImage(IDeckLink decklink)
    {
        IDeckLinkOutput op = null;

        IDeckLinkMutableVideoFrame mvf;

        op.CreateVideoFrame(1024, 768, 1024 * 4, _BMDPixelFormat.bmdFormat8BitBGRA, _BMDFrameFlags.bmdFrameFlagFlipVertical, out mvf);

        DrawFlower(ref mvf);

        op.DisplayVideoFrameSync(mvf);


    }

    private void DrawFlower(ref IDeckLinkMutableVideoFrame mvf)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile("D:\\ss\\NI.png") as Bitmap;

        var deckLinkCompatableImage = ResizeImage(bmp, 1024, 768);


        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        var imageBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(deckLinkCompatableImage, typeof(byte[]));

        IntPtr frameBytes; 
        mvf.GetBytes(out frameBytes);

        unsafe
        {

            byte* ptr = (byte*)frameBytes;

            Marshal.Copy(imageBytes, 0, frameBytes, imageBytes.Length);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the errors you get?

Comment: Since I dont have a blackmagic card yet the code is provisional but I am going to assume the IDeckLinkOutput since it is null will fail but I am not sure what to instantiate it with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know Decklink is very picky with formats...you have to configue an output, and make sure you display something compatible with that output format. 1024*768 is not either PAL, NTSC, 720p or any HD format compatible...